# Most efficient way to loop over huge amount of data coming from an API and import into WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, memory, timeout

I'm using a PHP cURL request to get a large amount of data (soccer matches) from an API (10,000 rows and growing).  I'm grabbing everything at once as an array and then looping over the entire thing.  Each row (match) is then checked to see if it has a corresponding post that already exists in WordPress.  If it does, then it is skipped - if not then it is imported as a new post.

I've had to increase a lot of PHP variables in order to keep it working, but it is becoming unsustainable due to the huge amount of data.  I'm wondering what the most efficient way to split this into smaller chunks would be?

The API does allow you to pass in a "page" parameter.  Is it possible to split the call up into smaller chunks using the page parameter while also ensuring that PHP does not timeout?  Would individual javascript AJAX requests be more efficient?  Looking for what is most efficient from a server standpoint.

```
private function syncMatches($event_id) {

    $get_matches = $this->API->GetMatches($event_id);

    foreach ($get_matches as $key => $match) {

        $match_id        = isset($match->MatchID) ? $match->MatchID : null;
        $match_event_id  = isset($match->EventID) ? $match->EventID : null;
        $match_date      = isset($match->EventDate) ? $match->EventDate : null;
        $match_away_team = isset($match->AwayTeamNameFull) ? $match->AwayTeamNameFull : null;
        $match_home_team = isset($match->HomeTeamNameFull) ? $match->HomeTeamNameFull : null;

        if (!$match_id || !$match_date || !$match_away_team || !$match_home_team) {
            continue;
        }

        $post_name = $match_date . ' - ' . $match_away_team . ' @ ' . $match_home_team;
        $post_id   = $this->existingRowHandler('match', 'match_id', $match_id);

        if ($post_id !== 0) {
            continue;
        }

        $post_meta = $this->createPostMeta($match);
        $insert_id = $this->insertPost($post_id, $post_name, 'match', $match_id, $post_meta);

    }

    return time();

    die();

}
```

Comment: Does the API allow you to get a full count of the number of items are available?

Comment: @DubVader Yep!  It gives you the total rows and total pages.

Comment: Ok I've provided a potential solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would try making an initial call to the API to get the total number of items.  Then doing multiple cURL calls to get the data in to a file or multiple files.  Then either get the data from the file, or from multiple files if you want to break it up.

Here is an example with creating multiple files:

```
function get_total_count() {

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://yourapiurl/?page=1');

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $data = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));

    curl_close($ch);

    // Get the total count

    $item_total = $data->totalCount;

    $page_count = $item_total / 1000; // Use whatever number you want to break it up by

    /* 
     * Round the page count up so if we get a page count with decimals we make sure to get the 
     * final page
     */

    $total_pages = ceil($page_count);

    // Return the final page count number

    return $total_pages;


}



function create_json_files() {

    // Get the number of pages in the report
    $report_pages = get_total_count();

    // Create an array range for the page count
    $pages = range(1, $report_pages);

    // Create array for the json files that will be created
    $json_files = array();

    // For each page in the report_pages array we'll create json file with data returned from the report

    foreach ($pages as $page) {

    $ch = curl_init();

    // Get each page of the smartsheet report

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://yourapiurl/?page=' . $page);


    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $data = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    // Name the file we will write to so we can push it to an array

    $file_name = "game_json_" . $page . ".json";    

    // Write data to the file   
    $the_file = fopen("game_json_" . $page . ".json", "w");
    fwrite($the_file, $data);
    fclose($the_file);

    // Add the new json file to the json files array    
    array_push($json_files, $file_name);

    }

    // Return the json files array to be used for other actions

    return $json_files;

}

function do_stuff_with_your_data() {

   $data_files = create_json_files();

   foreach($data_files as $file) {

      // Do stuff with your data

   }

}
```

Comment: Good idea to ease the grabbing of data, I'll experiment with it.  However, I think most of the server load comes from looping through all of the data once I have it.

Comment: Right.  But at least with files you have more control over some things you can do with the data. So you have several options as to compressing the data and reducing memory.

You also mentioned using multiple Ajax requests, so you could use this approach above, then call the individual Ajax requests as you mentioned, to pull data from the files and output them to the browser.  In this case you can run a job to pull data from the API every so often, then run the Ajax requests when you need the data, rather than hitting the API every time.